# Expose a cancellable Task

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm designing an API that exposes a cancellable `Task`, and want to make sure I have designed it correctly. Is there a standard pattern for exposing `Task`s (maybe something similar to the APM BeginXxx/EndXxx pattern)? Any suggestions to improve? See `MyAPI.Run`

Does `Test2` demonstrate the best way to run many `MyAPI.Run` tasks in parallel?

```
public static class MyAPI
{
    public static Task<MyResult> Run( CancellationToken token ) {
        // lazily create Task, so as to include the specified CancellationToken
        return new Task<MyResult>( MyPrivateAsyncMethod, token, token );
    }

    private static MyResult MyPrivateAsyncMethod( object state ) {
        CancellationToken ct = (CancellationToken)state;
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return new MyResult();
    }
}

public static class TestMyAPI
{
    // User can start the Task directly
    public static void Test1() {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        MyAPI.Run( cts.Token )
            .ContinueWith( task => Console.WriteLine( task.Result.ToString() ) )
            .Start();
    }

    // User must wrap in new Tasks to get Parent/Child relationship
    public static void Test2() {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
        {
            var childTasks = new[] {
                Task.Factory.StartNew<MyResult>( () => MyAPI.Run( cts.Token ).Result, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default ),
                Task.Factory.StartNew<MyResult>( () => MyAPI.Run( cts.Token ).Result, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default )
            };

            Task.Factory
                .ContinueWhenAll<MyResult>( childTasks, tasks => { foreach( var task in tasks ) task.ToString(); } )
                .Start();
        }, cts.Token );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your implementation that I would consider changing.

First off, this method:

```
public static Task<MyResult> Run( CancellationToken token ) {
    // lazily create Task, so as to include the specified CancellationToken
    return new Task<MyResult>( MyPrivateAsyncMethod, token, token );
}
```

This is dangerous - The *convention* for APIs returning `Task` or `Task<T>` is to return a "hot" Task.  This means that you should design your APIs to always return a task *which is already running*.

This is to prevent problems, like the one you have in your code above:

```
    MyAPI.Run( cts.Token )
        .ContinueWith( task => Console.WriteLine( task.Result.ToString() ) )
        .Start();
```

If you look at this, it can be rewritten as:

```
    Task<MyResult> original = MyAPI.Run( cts.Token );
    Task second = original.ContinueWith( task => Console.WriteLine( task.Result.ToString() ) );
    second.Start();
```

Here, you're actually calling Start on the wrong task - not the original task, but the continuation...  A typical approach would make "Run" return a hot task, which would allow you to write this as:

```
    MyAPI.Run( cts.Token )
         .ContinueWith( task => Console.WriteLine( task.Result.ToString() ) );
```

Again, this rears its head in your second example, as well.  You can `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and have it look at `MyAPI.Run`, but never actually call `Start` on the tasks inside...  As such, those tasks *will never start and never complete*.

Second, I would recommend using the new conventions for naming that are showing up in .NET 4.5, just for future proofing.  This is to make routines that return `Task` or `Task<T>` have the name with an `Async` suffix.  In this case, it would be `MyAPI.RunAsync`.  This will allow your code to look like the framework code that will crop up in the next release of .NET.

Finally, in regards to your last question:

> Does Test2 demonstrate the best way to run many MyAPI.Run tasks in parallel?

Actually, if you make the `Run` method return a running task, this becomes far simpler:

```
public static void Test2() {
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task1 = MyAPI.RunAsync(cts.Token);
    var task2 = MyAPI.RunAsync(cts.Token);

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll<MyResult>(
       new[] { task1, task2 }, 
       tasks => { 
           foreach( var task in tasks ) task.ToString(); 
       }, 
       cts.Token);
}
```

Comment: Regarding your Test2 rewrite, what happens to exception handling? Specifically, with a Parent/Child arrangement, I would `Try` the parent and catch an `AggergateException` of anything thrown by the children. How would this work in your rewrite?

Comment: @nmarler You'd have to handle it in the continuation - you can explicitly wrap a Try/catch around a call to Wait in the continuation to handle errors, if needed.

Comment: I'm mulling over the concept of only returning 'hot' Tasks. In my app I have a "SequenceManager" object that's responsible for running a handful of Tasks that live in other classes. When the SequenceManager is initialized, it was my intention to compose a Task of sub-object Tasks in a certain arrangement (some sequential to each other, some async). Then, at some point in the future, this "master" Task could be run. I think now that SequenceManager init should be simplified, and instead expose a RunAsync method that will compose the sub-RunAsyncs on the fly. Thanks, your advice is very helpful

Comment: @nmarler If you want to return something, but have it be a "cold task", I would consider returning a `Func<Task<T>>`.  This would make it obvious, and allow you to execute the delegate to start and get your actual Task.

Comment: One more question about returning hot `Task`s: what is the convention if the `Task` cannot be started? Return `null`? Throw? If convention is to throw (that's my guess), should the method throw individual exception, e.g., `ArgumentNullException`, or instead wrap in an `AggregateException`? Thanks

Comment: @nmarler Normally, if the task can't be started due to an argument/problem in the input, `ArgumentException` and its subclasses are typical.  If the error is from within the task, the task can throw an exception, which will put it into a faulted state...